# Pickle a sub class from a super class

Tags: python, pickle

I've done some digging and I've found a few threads on this, but I find them a bit hard to understand, so I'd love a little help. What I want to do is as follows

```
class A(object):

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.step1()
        #Want to save states of B and C here
        self.save()
        self.step2()
        self.step3()

    # HERE is where I need help
    def save(self):
         f = open("store_here.file", "w")
         pickle.dump(self, f)

class B(A):
     # Has own step1(), step2(), and step3() methods
class C(A):
     # Has own step1(), step2(), and step3() methods
```

I want to have the instances of classes B and C saved during the saved step, so I may then load them later, and skip step1(). I get the following error "can't pickle file objects", which is not that helpful.

Comment: Do you have a file object as instance attribute, perhaps?

Comment: Not really sure what this means? There is I/O occurring elsewhere while this is going on, but the file names should not clash. I have no variables or classes called file

Comment: No, `pickle` is complaining it cannot pickle your instance because there is a file object *somewhere* in its state. Either directly as an attribute or inside something else that is an attribute.

Comment: O, I think I follow. So If I am writing to a file from these subclasses, when attempting to pickle them, I am also attempting to pickle the file, and that is not good w/ pickle?

Comment: Check; either provide a custom `__getstate__` method that excludes that file object or don't store the file object as an attribute.

Comment: Last question, just did some google-ing for this getstate method, and I was curious if it will be implementable in class A, rather than having to make one for each new subclass I make?

Comment: That depends on how much you can predict the attributes of the subclasses; it could be as easy as `state = vars(self).copy()`, then remove stuff from that.

Answer (score 0):

If I use `dill`, which can serialize most things in python, I don't get an error.
(You can find `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation)

I'm assuming you want to do something like this…

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> class A(object):
...   def step1(self):
...     self.x = []     
...   def step2(self):
...     self.x.append(1)
...   def step3(self):
...     self.x.append(2)
...     print 'woohoo!'
...   def do_stuff(self):
...     self.step1()
...     self.save()
...     self.step2()
...     self.step3()
...   def save(self):
...     f = open('foo.pkl', "w")
...     dill.dump(self, f)
...   
>>> a = A()
>>> a.do_stuff()
woohoo!
```

Now build class B...

```
>>> class B(A):
...   def step1(self):
...     self.x = {}
...   def step2(self):
...     self.x['a'] = 1
...   def step3(self):
...     self.x['b'] = 2
...     print 'hoowoo!'
... 
>>> _a = dill.load(open('foo.pkl'))    
>>> _a.x
[]
>>> b = B()
>>> b.do_stuff()
hoowoo!
>>> _b = dill.load(open('foo.pkl'))
>>> _b
<__main__.B object at 0x110c16050>
>>> _a
<__main__.A object at 0x110c04a10>
>>> _b.x
{}
>>>
```

Note, I'm not storing the file as an attribute, anywhere.  Don't do that.  You could be smarter than I'm being above, and have an attribute to pass in the filename or something like that.